# Проблема с приставками при-/пре-

Tags: приставка

Почему в слове *признаюсь* пишется *при-*? Где-то пишут, что исключение, где-то — наоборот.

Answer (score 2):

Признаюсь  - 1 лицо ед.ч. от  "признаться"

1.- Признаться -открыто объявить, признать что-нибудь касающееся себя.

2.- Вводное слово в знач. "говоря откровенно", "если сказать правду".

Оба значения сводятся к одному - говорить правду, признать правду. Можно сказать "принять правду", а если принять, то попадает под значение "приближение, присоединение" - точно приставка при-, хотя приставка это только исторически, а вообще-то здесь **корень призна-, может быть, именно поэтому и говорят, что слово нужно запомнить, это словарное.**

А если подбирать однокоренные, то найдётся и слово с ударением на **при** - пр**и**знанный. Так что можно бы отнести и к гласным корня, проверяемым ударением. Однако я не считаю это верным объяснением, по своей природе это всё-таки приставка. Наверное, можно сказать, что это **слово с неясным значением,** которое следует запомнить. Кто-то может увидеть в нём и значение "доведение действия до конца", как, например, "придумать", "придушить", "притерпеться". Это тоже будет верное объяснение. В любом случае, это не значение "очень" или "пере", так что и методом исключения приходим к тому же написанию - ПРИ-.

Answer (score 0):

***Знать — признать.***

Что делает приставка ПРИ в глаголе *признать*?

1) Начнем с того, что пользователь вообще не должен решать такую глобальную задачу, а должен всего лишь **выбирать вариант ПРЕ или ПРИ**, так произносятся приставки одинаково.

В русских словах сделать это несложно, если обратиться **к обобщенным значениям приставок** и задать себе вопрос: это переход/превосходная степень или приближение? Или еще лучше: **это переход/ превосходная степень или обозначение направления для действия?**

Разумеется, нет в глаголе ***признать*** перехода и превосходной степени тоже нет, поэтому выбираем приставку ПРИ с направленным значением. Задача решена.

А теперь можно поговорить о приставках. Очень часто приставки выполняют двойную роль: изменяют вид глагола и обозначают какую-либо семантику (для глаголов это направление действия). О направленности глагола ***признать*** говорит его **связь с предметом**, это переходный глагол: признать (что?) свою вину.

2) **Какие ОШИБКИ совершают обычно пользователи при решении этой орфограммы.**

1) Они не пользуются **обобщенным значением приставок,** хотя это самое простое решение.

2) Они начинают придумывать разные истории, как будто для каждого слова есть свое **индивидуальное толкование**, вместо того чтобы составить обычную словообразовательную схему (кстати, это возможно только для приставки ПРИ).

3) И скорее всего, они вообще  не знают о том, что приставка ПРЕ **не выделяется как словообразовательный элемент, а входит в состав корня**. Например: преградить —  это непроизводное слово, оно не мотивируется словами без приставки ПРЕ. Поэтому нет у ПРЕ грамматической функции (образования вида): городить — пере/город/ить, но: преград/ить — преграждать.